# Bash: for interprets ".*" and transforms it into "." and ".."

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a script that will iterate over all arguments and performs a search for each of them. Example of usage:

```
./myScript "java" "chrome" "daemon"
./myScript "java" ".*"
```

The problem occurs when .* is used.

**First approach:**

```
patterns=$@
for pattern in ${patterns}; do
      ..
done
```

interprets .* as being . and .. (I wasn't able to find out why).

**Second approach:**

```
patterns=$@
for pattern in "${patterns}"; do
      ..
done
```

Considers all arguments as a single word (instead searching once for java and once for chrome, it will search for "java chrome").

Thanks!

Comment: `interprets .* as being . and ..` <-- This is correct, `*` will expand and `.` and `..` are both valid files.

Comment: Ok. But i wan't to skip that. Can you help me to do so?

Comment: If you want to prevent the expansion, use single quotes.

Comment: You may want to try `.[^.]*`

Answer (score 1):

the problem comes from assinging an array to a variable :

```
patterns=$@
```

to preserve arguments should be changed to

```
patterns=( "$@" )
```

then

```
for pattern in "${patterns[@]}"; do
    ..
done
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to store the patterns, you can just use this:

```
for pattern in "$@"; do
     ...
done
```